# JPA/Hibernate how to map a bean that represent "application properties"

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, repository-pattern

for a project I'm working on ( a cms solution), I have a table that store all the properties of the web site of the user (managed by the cms).

The table has this DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE SITE_OPTIONS(
    OPTION_ID int generated always as identity PRIMARY KEY,
    OPTION_NAME varchar(200) not null,
    OPTION_VALUE text,
    LANGUAGE_ID int not null
)
```

This is an example of the table content:

```
+-----------++---------------++------------------++-------------+
| OPTION_ID || OPTION_NAME   || OPTION_VALUE     || LANGUAGE_ID |
+-----------++---------------++------------------++-------------+
|         1 || SITE_TITLE    || My site title    ||           1 |  
+-----------++---------------++------------------++-------------+
|         2 || SITE_SUBTITLE || My site subtitle ||           1 |  
+-----------++---------------++------------------++-------------+
|         3 || TEMPLATE      || interior_designer||           1 |  
+-----------++---------------++------------------++-------------+
```

What I want, or better I would like, is a bean that represent the "siteoptions":

```
public class SiteOptions{
    private String siteTitle;

    private String siteSubtitle;

    private String template;

    //getters/setters
}
```

I have already a Repository based architecture (classic Repository Pattern impl) that I can use to implement the read/save functions.

Do you know if I can accomplish that with pure JPA/Hibernate?

Or have you ever managed this kind of situation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

When saving `SiteOptions`, simply transpose the options matrix to the entity class that corresponds to the database table structure:

```
@Entity
public class SiteOptionEntity {
   @Id
   @Column(name = "OPTION_ID")
   private Long id;

   @Column(name = "OPTION_NAME")
   private String name;

   @Column(name = "OPTION_VALUE")
   private String value;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "LANGUAGE_ID")
   private Language language;
   ...
}
```

Of course, use the appropriate id generator and decide whether to introduce a separate `Language` entity (as shown above) or to use the language id only.